# overriding adminhtml block template in community pool

Tags: templates, magento, overriding, block, adminhtml

Is it possible to override template located here `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/` (e.g. `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/edit/js.phtml`) by creating a new module **in community pool**?

So the thing is that I **don't want** to override it by placing the file (or anything) in local pool.

Is it possible to do that by extending of appropriate block class or something like that?

I've created the same file in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/my_directory/template/` and extended `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit` class in `/app/code/community/MyCompany/MyModule/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit.php` and don't have an idea of how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In your modules' config (`app/code/community/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml`) add the following section:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mycompany_mymodule>
                <file>mycompany_mymodule.xml</file>
            </mycompany_mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

This will make mage look for a new file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/layout/mycompany_mymodule.xml` which should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="customer.edit.js">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>mydirectory/edit/js.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

And then work on your file `app/design/adminhtml/default/template/mydirectory/edit/js.phtml`. There is probably no need to replace/extend the current block because it is already doing a good job as it is.